# Start processes at the same time

Tags: process, background-process

I have written a bash script which inturn needs to run around 130 Perl scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
perl file1.pl &
perl file2.pl &
perl file3.pl &
....
....
perl file130.pl &
```

The above bash script is configured in the cron to run after every 10 minutes. Is there any other way in which we can run all these 130+ perl scripts at a time ?

Answer (score 3):

```
for script in file*.pl
do
  perl "$script" &
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If the scripts are actually named like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..130}
do
    perl "file$i.pl" &
done
```